# genderdata package unavailable for R 3.2.3

Tags: r

When I try installing the package "genderdata" to R,

```
install.packages("genderdata")
```

I get the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>
> package ‘genderdata’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you try `devtools::install_github("ropensci/genderdata")`?

Comment: It looks like the devs were talking about this [here](https://github.com/ropensci/drat/issues/6) and thought it was fixed. Maybe you could alert them that this isn't fixed on CRAN.

Comment: From the documentation: If the genderdata package is not installed, install it from GitHub using devtools. If it is not up to
date, reinstall it.

Comment: Good points, although I got hit with the following ugly error:



Installing genderdata
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "c:/Temp/Rtmpw5ntwf/devtools1fc01d525501/ropensci-genderdata-ae29c3a"  \
  --library="C:/Users/thomzi12/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

Error: Command failed (65535)

Comment: I don't know how to begin with that error message. I guess I would download the zip file from github and try `devtools::install_local("foo.zip")`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in my version of R 3.1.1 and got the same error message as you. When I looked closer it also said:

> package ‘genderdata’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

I searched around some more and came up with this which worked for me.

```
options(repos = c("http://packages.ropensci.org/", getOption("repos")))
install.packages("genderdata", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type="source")
```

I got several warnings but it did install and can be loaded with

```
library(genderdata)
```

Comment: Hey! Ran these commands. Unfortunately, when I tried loading the package with library(genderdata), R told me the package didn't exist :(

Comment: Oh no! Try closing out R and rebooting your system and then reinstalling the package with this method. Are you using R studio? I wonder if that would make a difference. I'm working through R studio.

Comment: One more thing, search your computer for the genderdata package. It's possible that it didn't get put in the right directory so R can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing from a source that doesn't limit you based on your R version with devtools and github.

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_github("ropensci/genderdata")
library(genderdata)
```

Comment: I tried, but got hit with the error:

> install_github("ropensci/genderdata") 
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/genderdata@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/genderdata/zipball/master
Installing genderdata
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "c:/Temp/Rtmpw5ntwf/devtools1fc03d782af9/ropensci-genderdata-ae29c3a"  \
  --library="C:/Users/thomzi12/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

Error: Command failed (65535)